# Query very slow with date parameter, but fast with date as string in Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase, database-performance

I have fairly straight forward query which filters against a specific date in the where clause, like this:

```
declare @a_date date
set @a_date = '2013-09-17' 

select * from table t where t.date = @a_date
```

The above query takes forever, around 30 minutes to run.

Changing the query to the following takes only few seconds to run:

```
declare @a_date date
declare @string_date varchar(8)

set @a_date = '2013-09-17' 

set @string_date = convert(varchar(8), @a_date, 112)

select * from table t where t.date = @string_date
```

I am executing this query in Sybase ASE 12 using both RapidSQL and iSql and observing the same behaviour. According to Sybase date conversion, compatible date string format will be automatically converted to date type in RHS of the operator.

The field t.date is a datetime data type.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: I assume in the first code block you are actually setting the variable as is shown in the second code block?

Comment: Could you post the table DDL? Are you shure that the column "date" is actually defined as a DATE? If it was a string then for each row it will be converted to a DATE.

Comment: Your table is a datetime field and your query is using a date field - changing your variable to a datetime as well (i.e. to  ensure it matches the underlying table) should fix any issue. Also ensure that the column is suitably indexed on the table will help performance as well.